# How to generate an SVS file from multiple JPG tiles without decompress?

Tags: python, tiff

After I take all JPG tiles from an SVS file, I want to restore these files to SVS files. I use the tifffile library, but it seems that I can only operate by converting the JPG file into an array first. Converting JPG files takes a lot of time. Can I convert JPG files to SVS directly?

Comment: What's SVS please? Do you have a link?

Comment: https://openslide.org/

Comment: You can [write TIFF from a generator of pre-compressed segments](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/375d97f62df6482142b51f1b38a49bdd24d18a60/tests/test_tifffile.py#L13504-L13540) with tifffile.